# How to add an object inside another object?

Tags: java, class, oop, object

I am trying to create a console chess game.
I have Square class and my Chessboard have 64 Square objects. Also some of these squares have Piece object. **How can i add these  Piece objects into the Square Objects?***

```
public class Square {

    int column;
    int row;
    Piece piece;

    Square(){

    }



    public void setRow(int row) {
        this.row=row;
    }
    public void setColumn(int col){
        this.column=col;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(1< row && row <6)
            return " ";
        return super.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Via a setPiece method?

Answer (score 0):

```
public void setPiece(Piece piece) {
    this.piece = piece;
}
```

Adding this to your class lets you set a piece for each square. You can also define the piece in the square's constructor as this quarantees that a square always has a defined piece.

Comment: I don't want to add piece for each square. I want to add them to only 32 squares. Also each Piece can move, so that they can change squares. I'm really confused

Comment: " I want to add them to only 32 squares." can you explain this in details ?

Comment: @SachinKumar , I want 32 piece in my board. My board have 64 squares. I mean say,  I have a board which have 64 squares, and I 64 squares which some of squares have pieces. Totally I have 32 piece.

Answer (score 0):

You can add these useful methods to your `Square` class in order to set the various pieces between all the squares you want.

```
/**
 * @param piece to set on the actual square.
 */
public void setPiece(Piece piece) {
    this.piece = piece;
}

/**
 * Removes the actual piece on the square, if it exists.
 */
public void removePiece() {
    if(piece != null)
        piece = null;
}

/**
 * @param square where to move the piece on the actual square.
 * @return true if the piece were moved correctly, false otherwise.
 * e.g. of a false return is when the piece on the actual square is not present, in other words, it is null.
 * 
 * ATTENTION: Obviously the moved piece is removed from the actual square.
 */
public boolean movePiece(Square square) {
    if(piece != null) {
        square.setPiece(piece);
        removePiece();
        return true;
    } else
        return false;
}
```